# Null value from a drop-down list in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an drop-down which contains a list of projects. My problem is that I want to receive the value what I had select but instead I received null.

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/cidashboard/table}" th:object="${projectVariantSelected}" method="post">
 <p>Project variants options:</p>
 <select class="form-control"  th:field="*{projectVariantId}" >
      <option  th:each = "projectVariant : ${projectsVariants}"
               th:value="${projectVariant.projectVariantId}"
               th:text="${projectVariant.projectVariantName}" >
      </option>
 </select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I create a GET request:

```
public final Map< String, Object > modelAtribute = new HashMap< String, Object >();

    @GetMapping("cidashboard/filter/data")
    public String allDataForFilter(Model model, ModelAndView modelAndView) {
        model.addAttribute("projectsVariants", projectVariantService.findAllProjectsVariants());

       addAttributes(modelAtribute);

       return "test2";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public void addAttributes(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("projectVariantSelected", new ProjectVariant());
    }
```

And my POST request looks like that :

```
@PostMapping("cidashboard/table")
    public String createTable(@ModelAttribute("projectVariantSelected") ProjectVariant projectVariantSelected) {

        System.out.println("Project Variant selected: " + projectVariantSelected.getProjectVariantName() + " " + projectVariantSelected.getProjectVariantId());

        return "test1";
    }
```

When I try to print the output I received:

```
Project Variant selected: null 0
```

Comment: Your "projectVariantSelected-Hack" is unnessecary. Just send the ID to the createTable-method. There is no need for binding.

Comment: I removed the th:object and I writed :  <select class="form-control"  th:field="${projectVariantSelected.projectVariantId}" > but I received the same output

Comment: Try <select class="form-control"  id="projectVariantId" name="projectVariantId"" >

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code. Use `id` and `name` with value `projectVariantId` in select tag.

```
<select class="form-control" id="projectVariantId" name="projectVariantId"" >
```